# Fastest way to not let a value exceed another - C++

Tags: c++, numbers

I am currently trying to find I solution that will not let a value exceed a certain value, in this case, 0x1000 (4096). This is an easy solution, but the key here is speed.

```
int someVal = rand();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if(someVal > 0x1000)
        someVal = 0x1000;
    cout << someVal;
    someVal = rand();
}
```

That is too slow, unless of course there is no other way to do it. Thanks for any help, Hetelek.

Comment: not sending the value to stdout would speed things up ;-)

Comment: Why is this slow. Have you timed it? or looked at the assembly. The only significantly slow part of that loop is printing via `cout`

Comment: I know it is not because conditional statements are valuable...

@Jimmy - Those are just debug strings.

Comment: If you want to replace too-big values with the limit, then the operation is called "clamp", that's what you should look up. Although I suppose that actually it's only a half-clamp, since there's no lower limit.

Comment: Do you know it actually generates a branch statement (in assembley). Even if it does most processors do predictive branching and thus slows down is only seen if the prediction fails. These insights on how the code work by human mind are rarely accurate because the processor and compilers on modern systems are so complex and interconnected.

Comment: I think the question needs some more effort into arguing that the conditional statement is "too slow". Use `std::min()` and hope there's an assembly instruction for it in your architecture. Other than that, it's unlikely you'll find a consistently faster method without going into implementation details - which by the way you didn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try this;

```
floatValue = floor(floatValue * 0x1000 + 0.5)/0x1000;
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Does this solve your problem?

```
someVal = rand() % 0x1001;
```

Comment: That said, integer modulus is a famously slow CPU operation and the original if may be faster on many CPUs... worth benchmarking if you really care.

Comment: @Tony Delroy: more costly than generating a new random number? You must be kidding...

Comment: well, that gets back to how sensible the question is in the first place, but it does ask for something faster than the if / assignment and all I'm saying is that even though yours is a one-liner and branch free it's worth benchmarking IF you really care (which is a subtle way to say you probably shouldn't and won't afterwards)... ;-P

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to accomplish?

In this simple case you can check once after the loop. I' not sure what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same than it is explain in [c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `and` for masking:

```
someVal = rand() & 0xfff;
```

Comment: The question allows 0 to 0x1000 inclusive; your suggestion excludes 0x1000, folding it back onto 0.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the OP can live with that

Comment: Perhaps they can... it's not even terribly unlikely that a value from 0 to 0xFFF is what's really needed but the sample code was carelessly written... :-/.  In my experience, it's more common to want 4096 values (0..4095) than 4097.